# WebAPI Media Type Formatters not binding JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I'm quite frustrated that I can't figure this out considering I've done some binding in the past with MVC2+3 I have a method as such:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public ResponseModel Handler([FromBody]RequestModel tableRequest)
{
    return CreateTableResponse(tableRequest);
}
```

Which is fine except that I have no idea how its binding to this model - because I'm not sure how its binding I don't know how to apply custom binding by specifying different names for the values sent (sent with JSON 'application/json'):

```
public class RequestModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sName")]
    public String Name {get;set;}

    public List<AEntity> RequestEntities {get;set;}
}
```

I know that the `RequestEntities` are going to need some work in binding but why doesn't `RequestModel.Name` not bind to `sName` in the JSON? The `RequestModel.RequestEntities` are really awkward because the JSON being sent is in the form: `RequestModel.RequestEntities[0].ID` corresponds to `iID_0` Great huh? I am unable to change how the JSON is sent.

```
{
    "RequestModel" : 
    {
        "sName" : "john",
        "iID_0" : 1,
        "iID_1" : 2,
        "iID_2" : 3
    }
}
```

Is it possible to specify a MediaTypeFormatter or obtain the JSON as the parameter? How do I bind to that model?

All this magic behind the scenes does not help.

Comment: JsonProperty comes from the Newtonsoft JSON implemantation. ASP.NET default JSON serializer doesn't Understand this Attributes! Could you post the JSON? Maybe is just something wrong with the notation!

Comment: @Fals Just added the mock JSON

Answer (score 0):

The default ASP.NET ModelBinder can't process this kind of complex object. So, theres two ways to make this work.

1) Implementing an own ModelBinder, you can take a look here: [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.), that will take a bit of work to implement.

2) Making a little change to and action (I think that you should do this way!):

*Making our data posted with ajax like this:*

```
data: JSON.stringify({ name: 'name here', requestEntities: [...content as an array] }),
```

Obs: Make sure that every name in JSON matches properties names in the Model, or the default modelbinder will fail.

Sending name and Request separately:

```
[HttpPost]
public ResponseModel Handler(string name, List<AEntity> requestEntities)
{
    //Populate RequestModel here..
    return CreateTableResponse(name, tableRequest);
}
```

Hopes this help you!

Comment: How do I know if its using the DefaultModelBinder or the JsonMediaTypeFormatter? I also don't have access to the Json on the client side.

Comment: Depends on data type! JsonMediaTypeFormatter is used only to serialize JSONP! Implement an ModelBinder then, that builds you model back in the server :).